# Populating cells in separate sheet based on info on original sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

On my first sheet, I have 6 columns with lots of rows of data. The first column is date and the second is standard. In the second column, the info will either say met standard or not met standards. I want my second sheet to pull all of the rows that haven't met the standards.

I am new to Google Sheets, so I have attempted a few things, but I'm looking for some advise on what's the best way to do this.

I want my second sheet to be populated with data from the first based on a specific field in the second row of the first sheet.

Comment: For very general information, you can see google's [reference for best practices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/support/best-practices) with apps script. Beyond that, please [show what you've attempted and what hasn't worked](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) so we can help you understand what's going wrong.

Answer (score 0):

You might indicate whether this is a one-off, or regular event. In any event, it sounds like a `query` would meet your needs. There are dozens of topics on stack overflow (and the net generally) on using query. But it sounds like something like this would suit.

```
=query('sheetname'!A1:F27,"Select A, B, C, D, E where B='met standard'",-1)
```

**Instructions:**
1 - Put this formula in cell A1 of the second sheet
2 - Edit the formula to replace "sheetname" with the actual name of the first sheet.
3 - Edit the formula to replace the range (A1:F27 in this example) with the actual range of the data on the first sheet.

In this example, I've included Row#1 to capture headers. The "-1" at the end of the query has the effect of displaying those headers.

---

**Demo data**
[image: Demo Data]

---

**Query output**
[image: Query output]